# Data from radio button and div to textarea javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, textarea

I have a form with radio buttons, depending on which of the buttons is selected - a text in div is showing below the form. 
Now what i want is to take the info from the div (depends on which radio is selected) and put it automatically in textboxarea. Thank you for helping me!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.leasecond").hide();
    $("input[name$='months']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.leasecond").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.leasecond{
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi3"  />3 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni3"  />3 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi6"  />6 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni6"  />6 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
</table>


<div id="tbi3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 3 
</div> 
<div id="uni3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 3 
</div> 

<div id="tbi6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 6
</div> 
<div id="uni6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 6 x 
</div>

<textarea rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for. The line I've added will place the content from the visible div inside the textarea. What I am not sure of is if each time you select a different input the content of the div should be added to the textarea, or if the div content should replace the textarea content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.leasecond").hide();
    $("input[name$='months']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.leasecond").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
        // Place the text from the div in the textarea element.
        $("#textresult").text($("#" + test).text());
    });
});
```

```css
.leasecond{
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi3"  />3 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni3"  />3 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="tbi6"  />6 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                  <td><div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="months" value="uni6"  />6 месеца x </label>
     </div></td>
                </tr>
</table>


<div id="tbi3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 3 
</div> 
<div id="uni3" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 3 
</div> 

<div id="tbi6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с TBI, вноски 6
</div> 
<div id="uni6" class="leasecond">
    <input type="text" style="border: none;" readonly />Разсрочено плащане с UNI Credit, вноски 6 x 
</div>

<textarea id="textresult" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: lol same as my ans. seems I'm a bit slower than you. ganna del my ans then, good job.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted! I want the content in text area to change depends on which radio is selected - so perfect answer! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it is what you were looking for.

Comment: One simple question more? Can i hide the text from textarea? I mean i want to put it later in database, but i dont want the client to see it twice? THanks

Comment: Just hide the text? You could hide the entire textarea using CSS... would that be good enough? If the textarea is just for the text from the div you may also consider using an `<input type="hidden">` element.

Comment: I want adding the text to textarea, because my CMS will take it to database, but i dont want the client to see it...That`s why i want to do it with javascript

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear to me. Should the client (website visitor) be able to enter text in the textarea? You can't hide specific texts in the textarea, so if you don't want the client to so it you will have to place it inside some other element.